# Mysql : COUNT value by level ( if the level not exist the num wil be 0 )

Tags: mysql

I my try to group by field's value

> **(table)level_count:**

```
id  level

1   high

2   high

3   hgih

4   low
.

.

.
```

If `medium` is not exist in `level` but I want result like :

```
level   count 

high    3 

medium  0 

low     1
```

I try `IN` and `distinct` but they only found the exist value

Is there any way to `count` different `level` include does not exist's value ??

Comment: Post your sql that you have tried

Comment: This is a funny existential question: How can any SQL database count values that don't exist?  How will it know to add medium if it doesn't appear?  What is to stop it from adding Sleepy, Dopey, or duck?  (They don't appear, either.)  Is there a JOIN to all existing levels that you aren't telling us about?

Comment: Have a separate table that contains all the possible level values and do a left join on that.

Comment: I consider useing mysql  enough to solve the problem without PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already: The DBMS must know what levels exist (otherwise it wouldn't know that level 'medium' was missing from table `level_count`).

So create a table `levels` with one column `level`. Add three rows: 'high', 'medium', 'low'.

Add a foreign key on `level_count(level)` to `levels(level)`. This keeps you from storing typos like 'hgih' in your sample data.

The query is then:

```
select l.level, count(lc.level)
from levels l
left outer join level_count lc on lc.level = l.level
group by l.level;
```

Answer (score 0):

My original code using PHP with PDO

SQL:

```
SELECT `level` , count(`level`)  FROM `level_count` GROUP BY `level`
```

then push reuslut to `level` array, it will look like:

```
level['high'] = 3, level['medium'] = 0, level['low'] = 1
```

It's work but I think it is not perfect

So I think is there possible any SQL syntax can reach this purpose in the Outset